# Function not getting loaded onsubmit in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I have a simple form (removed irrelevant parts) but the `onsubmit` don't seems to be working.

```js
function DisplayOrder() { 
    document.writeln( "<h1>Order Details</h1>" );
}
```

```html
<form id = "myForm" action="" onsubmit="return DisplayOrder();"  > 
    <input type = "submit" id = "submit"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, even without `return false;` I edited your post and you can see it working.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You don't return false at the end of your function :</strike>

```js
function DisplayOrder() { 
    document.writeln( "<h1>Order Details</h1>" ); 
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form id = "myForm" action="" onsubmit="return DisplayOrder();"  > 
    <input type = "submit" id = "submit"  />
</form>
```

Add `return false` at the end of your function to prevent reloading the page and don't send the form.
`return true` sends the form. By default your form is sent directly if you do not add `return false`

**EDIT :**

Maybe your function is not loaded in your DOM. Try to declare your function like this :

```
DisplayOrder = function () { 
    document.writeln( "<h1>Order Details</h1>" ); 
    return false;
}
```

With this way `DisplayOrder` will be defined at run-time

Comment: why is `return false;` needed

Comment: ...actually the html is not getting displayed on the page `<h1>Order Details</h1>`

Comment: It will definitely not work with the code shown for `window.onload` snippet, since `onsubmit` handler is resolved in the global context.